# MongoDB: Get all documents from collection filtered by max value of some field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to know the best way to filter Mongo Collection by max value of some field. If I were to do the same thing in SQL I would apply the below query.

`select * from tableName where column1 in (select max(column1) from tableName)`

Given the below the sample input and output student. Here input dataset is filtered with the max value of StudentAge.

**Input**

```
_id StudentName StudentAge
1   John         15
2   David        16
3   Miller       15
4   Mike         16
5   Graham       16
```

**Output**

```
_id StudentName StudentAge
2   David        16
4   Mike         16
5   Graham       16
```

I tried looking up various questions on SO but I couldn't get across anything that matches my question.  I am using Mongo Compass to query the Mongo collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not as straight forward to do this in MongoDB although there are workarounds.

**Method - 1:**

One approach to implementing this is by using the MongoDB Aggregation query:

```
db.<Collection-Name>.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$<Key-Name>",
            "documents": {"$push": "$$ROOT"}
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "_id": -1
        }
    },
    {
        "$limit": 1
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$documents"
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": { newRoot: "$documents" }
    },
])
```

> Modify the `<Collection-Name>` and `<Key-Name>` with appropriate values.

This method is not recommended especially if the MongoDB collection consists of huge number of records in it.

**Method - 2:**

The second method is using the traditional MongoDB find method (although it involves two find commands.

```
var recordWithMaxValue = db.<Collection-Name>.find({}, {"<Key-Name>": 1}).sort({"<Key-Name>": -1}).limit(1);  // Init Cursor
db.<Collection-Name>.find({"<Key-Name>": recordWithMaxValue.next()["<Key-Name>"]});  // Get records with Max. value
```

This method is more recommended compared to the first one.

> Please point out if there are any better solutions

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I will read about the tags that you used and make sense of it. Will also wait for few days to see if we are getting any other better answer.

Comment: @hhharsha360.  If possible, can you tell me how I can do this in Mongo Compass?. Even if it takes multiple stages, thats fine.

Comment: Make sure that you are using the latest version of MongoDB compass. Open the required collection and click on the `Aggregations` tab. Click on the dropdown from the centre left panel and select the `$group` from the list. TYPE THE QUERY ALONE WITHOUT THE PIPELINE STAGE NAME IN THE TEXT BOX, example, only the quoted should be present : `{
"_id": "$<Key-Name>",
"documents": {"$push": "$$ROOT"}
}`. Once done click on the `Add Stage` button present at the bottom to add additional stages like $sort, $limit, etc. The results get altered on the right pannel as you add stages

Comment: Yes, I was able to follow the approach 1 in Mongo Compass and it worked fine. Thank you and I am marking your answer as accepted.